# base64 string different between c# and Delphi

Tags: c#, rest, delphi, base64

I write RESTserver with Delphi 10.3
The Service accepts 3 parameters. One of them is the string hold base64 string of PDF file.

When I create the Base64 String with Delphi as :

```
function  ConvertPdfFileToBase64D(PdfFileName : String; var Base64Str : String) : Boolean;
var
  success   : Boolean;
  b64       : String;
  fBytes    : TBytes;
  fSize     : Integer;

  function FileToBytes(const AFileName: string; var Bytes: TBytes): Boolean;
  var
    Stream: TFileStream;
  begin
    if not FileExists(AFileName) then
    begin
      Result := False;
      Exit;
    end;
    Stream := TFileStream.Create(AFileName, fmOpenRead);
    try
      fSize := Stream.Size;
      SetLength(Bytes, fSize);
      Stream.ReadBuffer(Pointer(Bytes)^, fSize);
    finally
      Stream.Free;
    end;
    Result := True;
  end;
begin
  Result := False;
  Base64Str := '';
  if FileToBytes(PdfFileName,fBytes) then
  begin
    //Base64Str := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(fBytes, fSize);
    Base64Str := TNetEncoding.Base64.EncodeBytesToString(fBytes);
    Result := True;
  End;
end;
```

when i get this base64 in the Delphi REST Api I decode the string and successfully save a PDF file.

when i send base64 string created in Visual Studio C# like :

```
Byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@textBox1.Text);
var content = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);
```

I get different base64 strings.

what is the right way to send base64 string as PDF file from C# to Delphi REST API

Comment: base64 != base64. There are some variants with slight differences(typically in padding behavior). I can't tell if there is a difference between Net and Delphi bit you may simply try. Encoding the same thing in both system and compare. If different then check for example against the list of variants in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) and decide what side to adapt to the behavior of the other with the then knowledge of what they actually do for base64 encoding.

Comment: Looking at the Delphi [docs](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.NetEncoding.TBase64Encoding.Create) there seems to be at least the option to change encoding behavior when you constructing a TBase64Encoding yourself.

Comment: Someone might want to remove the duplicate marker. It totally ignores the "interop" Part between native Delphi and Net.

Comment: @Ralf:  I don't see much of an "interop" between Delphi and C# here. OP only mentioned differences without showing the different strings or at least specifying their differences. And maybe the line `content = Convert.ToString(fileBytes)` is already the error, because this does not convert the bytes to Base64. The correct way is shown in the linked duplicate. If the OP is not satisfied with the linked Q/A, they can of course add a comment here and edit the question to make clear what makes their question different and why they didn't find a solution in the linked Q/A.

Comment: @jps Point taken I didn't even see the 2 lines of codes down there :(

Comment: @mazluta You should do the following to create a base64 string `Byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(@textBox1.Text);
var content = Convert.ToBase64String(fileBytes);`

Comment: Hi I'm Sorry this was just Test. i did : Convert.ToBase64String and it different string